# Trigger for account team member

Tags: apex, trigger, account-teams

I'm trying to add Account team member dynamically but my code fires error msg.Please go through the steps below.

- Parent Account(Lookup Field) on Account Object
- VPA(Checkbox) on Account Object.

If VPA == true then the owner of parent account to which it is lookup should be added as account teammember on account page.

```
trigger AccountTeam on Account (after update) {
    Integer newcnt = 0;
    Integer newcnt0 = 0;
    AccountTeamMember[] newmembers = new AccountTeamMember[]{};

    //list of new team members to add
    AccountShare[] newShare = new AccountShare[]{};

    //list of new shares to add
    Account a1 = [select id, parent.Id,Owner from account Where Id=:trigger.new[0].ParentID];
    ID uid = a1.Owner;


    //get the user id of the user running the trigger, anyone that changes the Account will added to the account team
    for(Account a:trigger.new) {
        AccountTeamMember Teammemberad=new AccountTeamMember();
        Teammemberad.AccountId=a.id;
        Teammemberad.UserId=uid;
        Teammemberad.TeamMemberRole = 'Account Modifier';
        newmembers.add(Teammemberad);
    }

    Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(newmembers,false);
    //insert any valid members then add their share entry if they were successfully added Integer newcnt=0;
    for(Database.SaveResult sr:lsr) {
        if(!sr.isSuccess()) {
            Database.Error emsg =sr.getErrors()[0];

            system.debug('\n\nERROR ADDING TEAM MEMBER:'+emsg);
        } else {

            newShare.add(new AccountShare(UserOrGroupId=newmembers[newcnt].UserId, AccountId=newmembers[newcnt].Accountid, AccountAccessLevel='Read',OpportunityAccessLevel='Read'));
        }
        newcnt++;
    }

    Database.SaveResult[] lsr0 =Database.insert(newShare,false);
    //insert the new shares Integer newcnt0=0;
    for(Database.SaveResult sr0:lsr0) {
        if(!sr0.isSuccess()) {
            Database.Error emsg0 = sr0.getErrors()[0];
            system.debug('\n\nERROR ADDING SHARING:'+newShare[newcnt0]+'::'+emsg0); 
        } 
        newcnt0++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very unsafe trigger behavior. `Where Id=:trigger.new[0].ParentID` you should _never_ write triggers that blindly grab data from the 0th record in the collection and presume that all records coming into the trigger are identical to the first one.

Comment: What is the error message that your code fires?

Comment: can you write the correct answer for it

Answer (score 1):

```
for(AccountTeamMember teamMember:[select UserId,TeamMemberRole from AccountTeamMember where accountId=:OPP.AccountID]){

                if (teamMember.TeamMemberRole=='Integration Manager'){
                    SVC.OwnerId = teammember.UserId;
                } else if (teamMember.TeamMemberRole=='Client Manager'){
                    SVC.Client_Manager__c = teammember.UserId;
                }  

            }
```

check this might be 1 solution to trigger for account team member